# How to Map the method having interface and class -flow- from action to delegate

Tags: java, delegates, struts2, action

Consider a method in delegate

```
Public void findThisMethod(String a,Set b,HashSet c){}
```

So from action class i want to map this method..

Can any one help me out for this case..

From action to delegate..

Note: in Delegate i had a method having one of the argument type as interface ie..Set..

Consider am having action class which extends GenericAction.java.. 
In genericaction we had generateRequest() method.. in that method, they are calling getDeclaredMethod() method in the delegate class.., 
but this method is not suitable for interface arguments..

Comment: You are talking about struts action ?

Comment: s struts action class to delegate class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your struts.xml (or in your config file for struts, assuming you are using xml for that) try this:

```
    <action name="loadResult" class="StrutsActionClass" method="findThisMethod">
        <result name="success">result.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: No dude, am not having xml to map.. i ll narrow down my question..  Consider am having action class which extends GenericAction.java.. in genericaction we had generateRequest() method.. in that method, they are calling getDeclaredMethod() method, but this method is not suitable for interface arguments.. do u understand my query now?

Comment: `this method is not suitable for interface arguments.` what do you mean by that ?

Comment: that mean.. i had a method in delegate having argument as interface instead of class.. ex.. having set instead of hashset